# On the spectrum of random regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

For a random $d$-regular graph, where $d$ can be fixed or can grow slowly with the size of the graph $n$, what can we say about its spectrum - Do you believe it has simple spectrum?

Thank you,

Comment: On the principle that it is easier to ask questions than to answer them: could you please edit your question and give a bit more information on what you've already tried to do towards answering this problem? For instance, why do you think it might have simple spectrum?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I believe that it will have simple spectrum for d >= 3 and it feels like something that should have been proved, though I can't actually find it.

There is a loose association between automorphisms of a graph and multiple eigenvalues, and as most regular graphs have trivial automorphism group we lose this source of multiple eigenvalues. There are no other (frequently occurring) "reasons" for a graph to have multiple eigenvalues and so in general they won't be there.

ADDED:

Here are some exact numbers for connected (pairwise nonisomorphic) cubic graph: disconnected graphs vanish numerically and so we can ignore them.

10 vertices - 19 graphs - 6 with no repeated eigs = 31% simple

12 vertices - 85 graphs - 18 with no repeated eigs = 21% simple

14 vertices - 509 graphs - 316 with no repeated eigs = 62% simple

16 vertices - 4060 graphs - 2181 with no repeated eigs = 54% simple

18 vertices - 41301 graphs - 26446 with no repeated eigs = 64% simple

(Actually this is growing more slowly than I expected... )

Answer (score 4):

In 1986, Noga Alon conjectured
in a *Combinatorica* article that,
for any degree $d \ge 3$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$,
most $d$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices have all their eigenvalues except $\lambda_1=d$
bounded above by $2 \sqrt{d−1} + \epsilon$.
In 2003,
Joel Friedman established this conjecture:
"[A proof of Alon's second eigenvalue conjecture](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=780542.780646),"
2003.
Some further developments on the distribution of the eigenvalues are reported
in a paper by Miller, Novikoff, and Anthony Sabelli,
"The Distribution of the Largest Nontrivial Eigenvalues in Families of Random Regular Graphs"
in [*Experimental Mathematics*, 2008](http://akpeters.metapress.com/content/310234x26083n370/).  Perhaps some of these references will help.

Answer (score 2):

I guessed no but Gordon has changed my mind for degree greater than 2.

If it has degree 2 it is a union of cycles. Eigenvalues are  $2\cos(\frac{2 \pi j}{k})$ for various $ k$. In particular 2 has multiplicity the number of components.

For random regular graphs of degree more than 2 I'd wildly guess that the eigenvalue behavior is like that of a  large random symmetric matrix. This has been well studied, but not by me, all I know is the phrase "Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble".

Some experiments with degree 3 graphs suggest that with 30 vertices one component is highly likely and there is a repeated eigenvalue ( most often 0) about 2% of the time. At 60 vertices it is more like 0.2%.

Comment: Think you're right: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310002 , which would make it follow Wigner's Semi Circle law.  As a heuristic, you can think of Erdos-Renyi random graphs as essentially being regular in their mean degree, so it's not so surprising that actual regular graphs have the same property...

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this answer to provide some additional references and information regarding the bulk spectrum of the adjacency matrix. (I believe that with probability $1$ the eigenvalues will be simple)

McKay's Law [[1]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379581901506) for random $d$-regular graphs states that the spectrum weakly converges to the spectrum of the universal cover of the graph, which is a $d$-regular tree in this case. The spectral measure is given by $$d\mu_{\text{McKay}}(x)=d\mu(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{d\sqrt{4(d-1)-x^{2}}}{2\pi(d^{2}-x^{2})}dx & |x|\leq2\sqrt{d-1}\\
0 & |x|>2\sqrt{d-1}
\end{cases}.
 $$

In other words, if we take a random $d$-regular graph $G_n$ with adjacency matrix $A_n$, and eigenvalues $\lambda_n\leq \dots \leq \lambda_1=d$, then for every $-2\sqrt{d-1}\leq a<b\leq 2\sqrt{d-1}$ we have

$$\frac{\#\left\{ \lambda_{i}:\ a\leq\lambda_{i}\leq b\right\} }{n}=\int_{a}^{b}d\mu_{McKay}(x)+o_{n}(1)$$
with probability going to $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Tran Vu and Wang [[2]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6646) showed that if $d\rightarrow\infty$ as the size of the graph goes to infinity then the spectrum converges to [Wigner's semicircle law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution). Note that for low fixed degree we don't get the semi circle - this is because the $2k^{th}$ moments are not simply the $k^{th}$ Catalan number multiplied by the spectral radius to the power of $2k$ - the base point has degree $d$ and this affects the calculation when $\frac{d}{d-1}\neq 1+o(1)$.

For a brief description of these results along with more references, I recommend Yufei Zhao's note [Spectral Distributions of Random Graphs](http://web.mit.edu/18.338/www/2012s/projects/yz_report.pdf)

**References:**

[1] Brendan Mckay, 1981, [The expected eigenvalue distribution of a large regular graph](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379581901506).

[2] Linh Tran, Van Vu, Ke Wang, 2010 [Sparse random graphs: Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6646).

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, a plot of the spectrum of the sum of 10 random permutation matrices
shows the (semi)circle law:

[image]